# Why my cron job is running every minute when it is scheduled to run every hour?

Tags: cron

I have a script that creates a cron job to take a backup of a local MongoDB. When I execute `crontab -l command`, I see following:

```
* */1 * * * cd /home/user/shell-scripts && sh mongo-backup.sh
```

I previously configured the same cronjob to run every minute but then I edited it. I have restarted my machine after editing the job.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `0` at place of first `*` like :

```
0 */1 * * * cd /home/user/shell-scripts && sh mongo-backup.sh
```

if you use * it means it will execute every minute.

Comment: I am trying your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy answer. Now the job is not running every minute. That's a partial success.

Comment: FYI, Backup scripts executes every hour on dot like 6 then 7 and so on with the solution you suggested. It doesnt execute hour after you create cron job. For example if you create cronjob at 5:27 then first execution will be at 6:00, second execution will be at 7:00 and so on.

Comment: yes , if you want to run every hour on 27 minute then you have to do like  :  `27  */1 * * * cd /home/user/shell-scripts && sh mongo-backup.sh`

Comment: @DarshanPuranik - take a look at some crontab examples and tutorial to better understand it, for example http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/ (but Google knows much more and there is always man crontab, although it's rather elaborate and long); also, you can just have `/home/user/shell-scripts/mongo-backup.sh` instead of `cd /home/user/shell-scripts && sh mongo-backup.sh`