# Cron Wont Run - Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: scripts, cron

So I've created a backup script that tar's up files, rsyncs them to a remote server, and removes the tar afterwards. I've manually tested the file and it runs, however I cannot get it to run via cron.

Script Details:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    792 Sep 21 18:44 backup.sh
```

Crontab Details:

```
* 04 * * * sh /home/user/scripts/backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Syslog Output:

```
Sep 23 16:25:01 user CRON[15244]: (root) CMD (sh /home/user/scripts/backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

I've attempted to run just /home/user/scripts/backup.sh without the sh in front also, however it gives the same syslog output.

Any help on this is appreciated. Without any real details in the syslog, I've run into a roadblock.

Comment: Maybe you should stop sending the output to `/dev/null` and see what it contains?

Answer (score 0):

The command is running since you're seeing it in syslog. I imagine you don't have a hashbang at the top of your shell script, are using bash syntax while running the job in sh, or are using a non-fully-qualified path (using just echo instead of /bin/echo). There's this answer to that problem:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash

Comment: I have altered crontab to have SHELL=/bin/bash at the top and adjusted the actual cron to remove the 'sh'. Still no dice.

Comment: Crontab suggests the format should be: 
# m h dom mon dow user command
but yours doesn't have a user
* 04 * * *  root sh /home/user/scripts/backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: @JonEdney you add a shbang #!/bin/bash at the top, not SHELL=

Comment: @JonEdney cron runs with a minimal shell and minimal envriontal variables. Use the FULL PATH TO BINARIES

Answer (score 0):

your cron job will create backup every day 04 AM every minute . your are creating backup every minutes so it may be your backup process take more than 1 minute. change first * to either 0 or some other. if you want to create backup once a day then use

```
0 04 * * * /home/user/scripts/backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

it will create backup everyday 04 AM.

or 
if you want to create backup every four hour then use like

```
0 */4 * * * /home/user/scripts/backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

no need to add `sh`. make sure you are giving full path of script.

you can learn more from [How do I set up a Cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) or any other blogs. 
also make sure you are setting this as a root user. i can't talk about your shell because i don't know what you written in shell.

go through [Reasons why crontab does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work) this is good explanation to find basic crontab issues. also you can see my answer for some help [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674278/why-my-cron-job-is-running-every-minute-when-it-is-scheduled-to-run-every-hour/674283#674283)

Comment: Thank you. I've altered my initial script, however as I've been working on this I've been editing the cron to run at specified times and still no change.

Answer (score -1):

Try to restart cron service.

```
/etc/init.d/crond start
```

and then check your process running or not.

Comment: Restarting the cron service was one of my first troubleshooting actions.